# CakePHP 3.6.13 and PHP 7.2.5: Stacktrace not showing

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, php-7

We've recently updated our CakePHP 3 project to PHP 7.2.5 (from 5.6.36). We've noticed that the stacktrace no longer shows when an error is thrown.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxpj3.jpg

In the screenshots above is the same example error running locally. No settings were changed, just ran it on 7.2.5 then again on 5.6.36.

Any ideas why this has changed?

Comment: Syntax error, without share your code how we can ensure that you didn't make any mistake ?

Comment: @AlimonKarim I purposefully put a random '?' in the code to throw a syntax error. The error isn't important and is just for example purposes, it's the error notice that's returned. It used to return the error with the full stacktrace on 5.6.36. On 7.2.5 it doesn't.

Comment: Did  you check extension in your new php version ?

Comment: @AlimonKarim did a diff between the two php.ini files. All the same extensions are used. I've also checked the whole file for other differences but there are none that would relate to or impact debugging.